# Reading in a conf file as a property list

Tags: external-files, expl3, l3prop

I'm not worried about supporting sections, although a bounty would be given for doing so :)

Here's what I have so far, but it produces strange output for `#2`:

```
\begin{filecontents}{test}
\Property this property = some value
\Property k = v
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \Property #1=#2^^M
  {
    1:#1\par
    2:#2\par
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\input{test}
\end{document}
```

Ideally, I would like to have a syntax like

```
\begin{filecontents*}{test.conf}
this property = some value
k = v

# bounty
[section]
property=value
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}
\conf_load:Nn \l_tmpa_prop { test.conf }

% outputs {some value} (brace groups irrelevant)
\conf_get:Nn \l_tmpa_prop { this ~ property }

% bounty; outputs {value} (brace groups irrelevant)
\conf_get:Nnn \l_tmpa_prop { section } { property }

\end{document}
```

How can this be accomplished?
I should note that the details of the interface / naming is just a suggestion.

### Ideas

(a work-in-progress list)

- Reading in the file and mapping a macro over each line; doesn't support sections
- Making necessary characters active for the read and practicing dark magic

Comment: One way would be to use [the `datatool` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool). Do you have a preference for using `expl3`?  Also, it would be helpful if your provided an actual list of `<property name>`, `<property value>` pairs.  Specifically do you need to be able to handle any of the special LaTeX characters ?

Comment: @PeterGrill Unfortunately, *every* character is fair game.  I do have a preference for `expl3`, but if a wrapper can be created, I'm fine with that. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this what you have in mind?

I define a `toplevel` property list and a `section` one; add the plists you need.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{test.conf}
this property = some value
k = v

# bounty
[section]
property=value
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\confload}{m}
 {
  \allred_conf_load:n { #1 }
 }

\prop_new:N \g_allred_conf_toplevel_prop
\prop_new:N \g_allred_conf_section_prop
\tl_new:N \l__allred_level_tl
\ior_new:N \g_allred_read_conf_stream

\cs_new_protected:Npn \allred_conf_load:n #1
 {
  \group_begin:
  \tex_endlinechar:D \c_minus_one % Ugly! Complain with the team!
  \char_set_catcode_comment:n { `\# }
  \ior_open:Nn \g_allred_read_conf_stream { #1 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l__allred_level_tl { toplevel }
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_allread_read_conf_stream
   {
    \tl_if_blank:nF { ##1 }
     {
      \__allred_process_line:x { \tl_trim_spaces:n { ##1 } }
     }
   }
  \ior_close:N \g_allred_read_conf_stream { #1 }
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__allred_process_line:n #1
 {
  \str_case_x:nnF { \tl_item:nn { #1 } { 1 } }
   {
    { [ } { \__allred_process_newlevel:n { #1 } }
   }
   {
    \__allred_process_property:n { #1 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__allred_process_line:n { x }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__allred_process_newlevel:n #1
 {
  \__allred_process_newlevel:w #1
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__allred_process_newlevel:w [ #1 ]
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__allred_level_tl { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__allred_process_property:n #1
 {
  \__allred_process_property_aux:www #1 ==\q_stop
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__allred_process_property_aux:www #1 = #2 = #3 \q_stop
 {
  \prop_gput:cxx { g__allred_conf_ \l__allred_level_tl _prop }
   { \tl_trim_spaces:n { #1 } }
   { \tl_trim_spaces:n { #2 } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_gput:cnn { cxx }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\confload{test.conf}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_show:N \g__allred_conf_toplevel_prop
\prop_show:N \g__allred_conf_section_prop
\ExplSyntaxOff


\end{document}
```

This is the output on the terminal

```
The property list \g__allred_conf_toplevel_prop contains the pairs (without
outer braces):
>  {this property}  =>  {some value}
>  {k}  =>  {v}.
<recently read> }

l.78 \prop_show:N \g__allred_conf_toplevel_prop

? 
The property list \g__allred_conf_section_prop contains the pairs (without
outer braces):
>  {property}  =>  {value}.
<recently read> }

l.79 \prop_show:N \g__allred_conf_section_prop
```

Comment: This is *fantastic*! A tick just doesn't seem to be enough, thank you!  I'll add the bounty as promised when I am able to within the restrictions of StackExchange.

Comment: On `\endlinechar`: the reason there's not an interface is that it's not that clear what one should be. It's better, long term, to add things only when we are reasonably clear what's the 'correct' approach rather than add half-tested ideas then have to revise them. With `\endlinechar`, use cases are rather rare and the team haven't needed it beyond places where a `:D` use is OK, at least to date.

Comment: @JosephWright A place where setting `\endlinechar` to –1 can be useful is certainly `\ior_map_inline:Nn`; maybe `\ior_map_inline_no_end_line:Nn` that does some trickery to resurrect the current value at the end? Sooner or later something like `\parameter_set_endlinechar:n` will be needed (and the same for all other internal parameters).

Comment: @egreg Isn't that normally covered by the string mapping case?

Comment: @JosephWright That's a very different thing, as the tokens are read in with category code 12, which may not be desired.

Comment: @egreg Ye, I know :-) I've only needed to either grab stuff either as TeX tokens (with endlines) or as strings. Couldn't you just test for `\par` here and leave the `\endlinechar` alone?

Comment: @JosephWright Possibly so, but I don't like it: what if the reading happens when `\endlinechar` is `a`? I need predictable input from the file.

Comment: `\g_allread_read_conf_stream` can't tell if typo or pun :)

Comment: @SeanAllred Typo. ;-) I also added closing the stream, which I had forgotten.

Answer (score 10):

My solution uses no expl3, no special latex macros, only TeX primitives. Just for comparison. The coding of this task begins from line 11 (first ten lines are copied as universal macros from OPmac).

```
\bgroup \catcode`!=3 \catcode`?=3 % \replacestrings, \addto, \sxdef from OPmac
\gdef\replacestrings#1#2{%
   \long\def\tmp##1#1##2!{\ifx!##2!\addto\tmpb{##1}\else\addto\tmpb{##1#2}\tmp##2!\fi}%
   \edef\tmpb{\expandafter}\expandafter\tmp\tmpb?#1!%
   \def\tmp##1?{\def\tmpb{##1}}\expandafter\tmp\tmpb
}
\egroup
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\sxdef#1{\expandafter\xdef\csname#1\endcsname}

% \readconf config_file 
\newread\infile
\def\readconf #1 {\bgroup \catcode`\#=14 \endlinechar=-1
   \def\sectionconf{global}\openin\infile=#1 \readconfA
}
\def\readconfA{\ifeof\infile \egroup \else
   \read\infile to\tmp 
   \expandafter\readconfB\tmp\par
   \expandafter \readconfA\fi
}
\def\readconfB#1\par{\ifx\par#1\par \else \readconfC#1\par \fi}
\def\readconfC#1#2\par{\ifx[#1\expandafter\readconfD \else\expandafter\readconfE\fi#1#2\par}
\def\readconfD[#1]#2\par{\def\sectionconf{#1}}
\def\readconfE#1\par{\def\tmpb{#1}\replacestrings{= }{=}\replacestrings{ =}{=}%
   \expandafter\readconfF\tmpb\par}
\def\readconfF#1=#2\par{\setkeyval{#1}{#2}}

\def\setkeyval#1#2{\expandafter\ifx\csname conf:\sectionconf\endcsname\relax
   \sxdef{conf:\sectionconf}{}\fi
   \sxdef{conf:\sectionconf}{\csname conf:\sectionconf\endcsname{#1}}%
   \sxdef{key:\sectionconf:#1}{#2}%
}

% \showconf[section]
\def\showconf[#1]{\def\sectionconf{#1}\message{SECTION [#1]:}%
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter \showconfA \csname conf:#1\endcsname \relax
}
\def\showconfA#1{\ifx\relax#1\else \showconfB{#1}\expandafter\showconfA\fi}
\def\showconfB#1{\message{{#1} => {\csname key:\sectionconf:#1\endcsname}}}

\readconf test.conf

\showconf [global]  % SECTION [global]: {this property} => {some value} {k} => {v}
\showconf [section] % SECTION [section]: {property} => {value}

\end
```

Comment: `+1` Wow! Very, very impressive! `:)`